# $\int_b^X f(t) dt$ where $X$ is a random variable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

Let $f$ be a real integrable continuous positive function on the real line. Let $b \in [-\infty,\infty)$. I am looking at

$$\int_b^X f(t) dt$$

where $X$ is a given integrable random variable.

I would like to express $E[\int_b^X f(t) dt]$. Is it true that $E[\int_b^X f(t) dt]=\int_b^{E[X]} f(t) dt$ ? If not, is there a nice way of writing it?

EDIT:  $E[\int_b^X f(t) dt]\neq\int_b^{E[X]} f(t) dt$. If $F(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$, we can see that $E[F(X)-F(b)]$ is not necessarily equal to $F(E[X]) - F(b)$

Comment: What properties does the function $f$ have?

Comment: I like the question but it's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here @W.Volante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Let: $$\Phi(x)=\int_b^x f(t)\d t$$

And remember the Law of the Unconscious Statistician:

$$\E(g\circ X)=\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\cdot f_X(x)\d x$$

In particular, letting $F_X^\pm$ denote the upper and lower tails respectively of the c.d.f. of $X$, and $f_X$ the p.d.f of $X$, which are related by $F_X^-=1-F_X^+$:

$$\begin{align}\E\left(\int_b^Xf(t)\d t\right)&=\E(\Phi\circ X)\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_b^x f(t)f_X(x)\d t\d x\\&=\int_{b}^\infty\int_t^\infty f(t)f_X(x)\d x\d t+\int_{-\infty}^b\int_{-\infty}^tf(t)f_X(x)\d x\d t\\&=\int_b^\infty f(t)\cdot F_X^+(t)\d t+\int_{-\infty}^bf(t)\cdot F_X^-\d t\\&=\int_{-\infty}^bf(t)\d t+\int_b^\infty f(t)\cdot F_X^+(t)\d t-\int_{-\infty}^b f(t)\cdot F_X^+\d t\end{align}$$

I don't think you can do any better than this. I definitely don't think this will be $\int_b^{\E(X)}f(t)\d t$ unless you are working with a very lucky special case.

Comment: If $x\in (-\infty,b)$ then the upper bound of the inner integral $\int_b^xf(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t$ is smaller than the lower bound. So I think you would have...

Comment: $$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_b^{x}f(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x &=&\int_{-\infty}^b\int_b^{x}f(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x+\int_b^{\infty}\int_{b}^xf(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x \\ &=& -\int_{-\infty}^b\int_x^{b}f(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x+\int_b^{\infty}\int_{b}^xf(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x  \\ &=& -\int_{-\infty}^b \int_{-\infty}^tf(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t + \int_b^{\infty}\int_t^{\infty}f(t)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t\end{eqnarray*}$$